# Delay rendering or force re-rendering in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

In my Flex application, using a custom control, I am making a JSON request to grab some data from the server. My rendering depends on this data such as knowing how many boxes to draw. How can I either force the rendering to wait until I've got the data before drawing to screen or have the boxes draw once we receive the data?

I have an event listener for Event.COMPLETE for my JSON request and in there, I call methods that add to the control. I've tried invalidateDisplayList but that doesn't seem to do anything for me?

Comment: Try using the static method UIComponent.suspendBackgroundProcessing().  It stops all calls to the lifecycle methods.  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#suspendBackgroundProcessing().  You can resume it with UIComponent.resumeBackgroundProcessing().

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a 'blank' state to your component that would be active until you have the final data.
This state could say "loading" for example.
Then you change state and render the proper layout